# Developer dashboard not retrieving anything

Tags: sharepoint-server, performance, dashboard

I have enabled developer dashboard in my site, when I click on the dashboard on the tp right side of the page, I don't see any thing retrieved. is there any special settings i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Developer dashboard having some dependency on the Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application. if that service is not created then you will get the issue

Try to create the Usage Application using this command

```
New-SPUsageApplication -Name "Usage Application" -DatabaseName "SP2013A_Logging"
```

Now close the browser and reopen it and test.

[Developer Dashboard shows no data "issue"](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-developer-dashboard-shows-no-data-issue)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50174/discussion-on-answer-by-waqas-sarwar-mcse-developer-dashboard-not-retrieving-any).